# Notation for assigning observations to a random variable

Tags: statistics, notation, random-variables

I want to assign some observations to a variable $X$, but I am unsure what the correct notation (if any) would be. At the moment I am doing it like this:

> For the following set of observations for X,
>   $$1,8,1,5,8,6,3,3,3,7$$
>   ...

But I was wondering if there was any actual notation where I could write something like this:

> For the following set of observations
>   $$X = \{1,8,1,5,8,6,3,3,3,7\}$$
>   ...

I dont think the latter is correct, since the random variable $X$ is not actually a set, but I wanted to know if there was any sort of similar notation to indicate the values observed for $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blitzstein considers in his [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466575573)  the 5x flipping a coin and writes:

- The **random variable** $X = \{\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\}: x_i \in \{head, tail\}\}$.
- The **realisation** of five flips: $\vec x = \{head, tail, tail, tail, head\}$.

Do not mix up the realisation and the random variable. These are to different things.